# CSS not completely rendered when browser first launched

Tags: css, browser, rendering, blogger

I'm having a relatively heavily customized Google Blogger blog template [here](http://www.malaysiatraining.net/), but the page doesn't seem to render completely during the first launch of the browser (including Chrome, IE10 and Firefox 20). If you refresh the page or landed from another page, however, it works. For screenshots, please refer to the comment below.

I do have the mixture of inline style sheet, external css files, those that declared in the `<head>` section and some even within the `<body>` tag. I know putting the `<style>` tag inside the `<body>` isn't really a good practice, but Blogger doesn't seem to allow me to include blog post specific css file with the `<link>` tag (even with the use of `<b:if>` condition).

I wonder if any of the above could be the cause of my rendering issue as mentioned earlier? Thanks in advance!

NOTE: To reproduce, you may need to follow these steps:

1. Go to my website: http://www.malaysiatraining.net/
2. Leave the tab open and close your browser. Make sure the 'open last used' option is selected.
3. Launch your browser again and notice the CSS rendering effects.

Comment: View sample screenshots here:
1. [When browser first launched](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-VvdqjLtGeWo/UY9q_d59KyI/AAAAAAAAE7k/SC6LYEY9FoQ/s500/after-refresh.jpg)
2. [After refreshing the page](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-TsLLb_AFImM/UY9q_gMSjjI/AAAAAAAAE7o/ZxUywFkQFrQ/s500/before-refresh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your site using [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/) and looking at the Timeline tab, the problem probably lies with `http://jotformpro.com/min/g=feedback2` which seems to be located in the following widget:

```
<div id="HTML6" class="widget HTML">
```

I suggest that you temporary remove that widget to see if it improves the loading time of your site.

You can see GTmetrix complete results of your site [here](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.malaysiatraining.net/kOX0Mrlz).

Comment: Thanks for the check and the analysis with GTmetrix! I'll try it out and get back to you again!

Comment: I've removed `http://jotformpro.com/min/g=feedback2` and replaced with their latest recommended url: `http://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/feedback2.js?3.1.2625`. I can't afford to remove jotform because it's the core part of my business. Besides, I also fixed some of the image dimensions recommended by GTmetrix. The problem seemed to be solved now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could also make separate thumbnail images in "5 essential courses" section. At the moment they are quite large (250x250 but are shown 4x smaller).

Comment: Yes, I think I should scale down the size at the image file level also. Thank you very much!